# Firefox changes Google results URLs to direct

Tags: firefox, google-search

Suppose I am googling for a word, like "[firebug](http://www.google.com/webhp?pws=0&gl=US#pws=0&gl=US&sclient=psy-ab&q=firebug)":

The first link Google gives me looks like this:

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=firebug&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgetfirebug.com%2F&ei=sHmHUfaMLIao4gTX7oGgDg&usg=AFQjCNGT1rhhsYGPQx5Vr5A8RvhIgdSp9g`

So, Google is redirecting me to the page. Is it possible in Firefox to change those URLs to the direct links? Taking this portion:

`url=http%3A%2F%2Fgetfirebug.com%2F`

and decoding it.

Comment: See also: [Turning off Google search results indirection](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22291)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Remove google search redirects](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/google-no-tracking-url/) addon.

> Google uses a redirection link to track your clicks. This addon simply removes that redirection and turns every search result in its original link, saving your time and giving you more security.

Or without the addon: [Remove Google Redirection userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/98394).

> Remove redirection and click-tracking in Google search results.

Comment: The Firefox addon no longer rewrites the URLs in the HTML, so you can't copy the links anymore.